# LinqToExcel on Windows7 64 bit with office 64bit

Tags: c#, ms-office, linq-to-excel

I have created windows forms application using linqtoexcel to read excel files it runs fine on windows 7 32/64 bit with office 32 bit but on windows 64 bit with office 64 it throws 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Can anyone help me how I can run my application on 64bit office

Comment: Hi which version of office are we talking about? 2010 64bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install Access Database Engine. More details [Office Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

If your project use x86 LinqToXml install x86 otherwise x64 version of Access Database Engine. For x64 Windows and x64 Office can be used also x86 LinqToXml and Access Database Engine.

I successfully test this on

- Win 64, Office 64, Access Database Engine 64, LinqToXml 64 and output target project x64
- Win 64, Office 64, Access Database Engine x86, LinqToXml x86 and output target Any CPU.

Comment: Do I need to build my application as x64

Comment: I successfully test this on Win 64, Access Database Engine 64, Linq to XML 64 and output target project x64. I guess that for 32b target project Access Database Engine 32 will needed to be install.

Comment: Hi, I did some tests and updated my answer. I guess that you dont need to change output target of your application. Just only install right ADE according to used Linq-to-xml platform version.

Comment: I guess you mean LinqToExcel and not linq-to-xml