# Could not load file or assembly 'LinqToExcel, Version

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-excel

I am trying to read an xlsx file.

I got exception that

```
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. c#
```

then I installed it from here

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
```

then I changed the `platform target` to `x64`

now i got this exception:

```
BadImageFormatException was unhandeled

{"Could not load file or assembly 'LinqToExcel, Version=1.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c8ea65a58f03f1f' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."}
```

#### Update 1

I already installed the linq_to_excel
using

```
Install-Package LinqToExcel
```

and then add the lib files to references

Comment: where is the answer please? I didn't saved the links

Comment: Which version of the Microsoft Access Database Engine did you install?  If you installed the x64, I'd try uninstalling it and installing the 32 bit version.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of ...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954762/linqtoexcel-on-windows7-64-bit-with-office-64bit

Comment: @Mick yes using the 32 was he cure

Answer (score 23):

You have two options to solve

1. Enable IIS to run 32 bits app
2. Install LinqToExcel_x64

Comment: I googled the error message literally. Arrived at this Q&A. Executed your number one option. And the problem was gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

if change 32 bit app in iis From false to true,all conflicts about exteltolinq version solve

Answer (score 0):

Please install Microsoft office in your machine it will automatically solve your problem. It worked for me as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).